# Как правильно сохранить данные бд

Tags: база-данных

Есть данные которые должны хранится в бд(mysql)Например пусть это будет велосипед, марка bmx. У этого велосипеда есть описание (Колесо:20,руль:сталь,диски:хром). Как сохранить и вывести из бд  название мне понятно.

Как правильно сохранить описание велосипеда? Допустим у меня каждый раз будет новое описание продукта.

Comment: Какая именно СУБД планируется? Реляционная или NoSQL? Поля в описании могут быть разными или их набор предопределён?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE opisanie(
opicanie_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
koleso VARCHAR(20),
rul VARCHAR(20),
diski VARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE velosiped(
velo_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
marka VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
opisanie_id INT,
FOREIGN_KEY(opisanie_id) REFERENCES opisanie (opicanie_id)
                      );
```